# Search folder only displaying certain words

Tags: linux, centos

I have a folder with the following files:

```
ondemand_kvm131_img.2
vm114_img.2
vm114_img.3
ondemand_vm205_img.3
label_ondemand_kvm131_img.1
vm117_img.1
```

I'd like to **only** display the "names", so in this case the output should be

```
kvm131
vm114
vm114
vm205
kvm131
vm117
```

How can this be done? By using sed? Grep? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ls -1 | sed 's/_img.*//;s/.*_//'
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways this can be done, depending on the precise formatting of the names and what you plan to do with it. The most simple would probably be a `ls | sed`:

```
$ ls | sed 's/^\(.*_\)*\([^_]*\)_img\.[0-9]/\2/'
kvm131
kvm131
vm205
vm114
vm114
vm117
```

If your file names are sane and you just want a visual look this will do fine, but if you're doing more with the names there is the potential for errors on odd file names. You can get them individually like so:

```
$ for file in *; do left=${file%_img.?}; base=${left##*_}; echo $base; done 
kvm131
kvm131
vm205
vm114
vm114
vm117
```

Replace the `echo` with your command of choice. Both of these can be altered to match the format more closely, if you have a different format overall.